change AMP without changin main domain
I'm currently focused on SEO. While I've achieved ranking success with certain keywords, governmental website blocks in my country have posed challenges. This necessitates domain changes and URL redirections for SEO recovery. However, the process can take a few days to regain ranking. Is there a way to change the AMP address without altering the main domain?
I have tried to change the amp but it didn't work
